# How to correctly handle this AJAX request that send an array to a Spring MVC controller method? Why it can't work?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am pretty new in Spring MVC and I have the following problem trying to handle an AJAX request that send an array of int to a controller method.

So I have the following situation. I have this JQuery function:

```
// It is global and it is initiazilized by another function:
var checkedRowList = new Array();

// SOME OTHER CODE THAT INIZIALIZED THE checkedRowList array here
...............................................
...............................................
...............................................

$('#validaButton').click(function() {

    alert("validazione");
    alert("CHECKED ROWS: " + checkedRowList.length);
    alert(checkedRowList[0]);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {'checkedRowList' : checkedRowList},
        url: "validaProgetti"
    }).done(function(response) {
        alert("SUCCESS");

    }).error(function(xhr) {
        alert("ERROR");
        manageError(xhr);
    });

});
```

So the **checkedRowList** is correctly initizialized (I checked it) and I use the **ajax()** function to send it toward the **validaProgetti** resource using a **POST** request.

Then into a controller class I have this method that have to handle the previous request:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "validaProgetti", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String validaProgetti(@RequestParam List<Integer> checkedRowList,  Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {

    System.out.println("Numero progetti da validare: " + checkedRowList);

    return "blablabla";
}
```

As you can see it handle HTTP Post request toward the **validaProgetti** resource. And Inside it I have specify the **RequestParam List checkedRowList** to retry the array passed by the AJAX request.

But it don't work because when the AJAX request is performed it don't enter into the **validaProgetti()** method and it shown the **alert("SUCCESS");** popup.

Why? What am I missing? How can I fix this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I see you missed two things.
 The first one is that in the Spring Web MVC controller. You don't pass a `RequestParam` but `RequestBody`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "validaProgetti", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String validaProgetti(@RequestBody List<Integer> checkedRowList) {

    System.out.println("Numero progetti da validare: " + checkedRowList);

    return "blablabla";
}
```

The second one is related with your Ajax request. You should send javascript array formatted as JSON. This is done via the function `JSON.stringify()`, which converts `js` value into `json`.

```
$('#validaButton').click(function() {

    alert("validazione");
    alert("CHECKED ROWS: " + checkedRowList.length);
    alert(checkedRowList[0]);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(checkedRowList),
        url: "validaProgetti",
        contentType:"application/json"
    }).done(function(response) {
        alert("SUCCESS");

    }).error(function(xhr) {
        alert("ERROR");
        manageError(xhr);
    });

});
```

Answer (score -2):

Also you may change the request mapping when defining in java code. Since it is a relative path, it would be confusing in some cases.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/validaProgetti", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String validaProgetti(@RequestBody List<Integer> checkedRowList) {

    System.out.println("Numero progetti da validare: " + checkedRowList);

    return "blablabla";
}
```